# <Link to = "/cart" ></Link> changes the url but my cart component is not getting rendered

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router

In my app I am using `react-router-dom`, when I go to the /cart page the url is getting changed but the cart component is not getting rendered.

This is the App.js component :

```
import React, {useEffect,useState} from 'react';

import {SignUp,SignIn,Homepage,Cart} from './Components'

import {AuthProvider,useAuth} from "./contexts/AuthContext";

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import PrivateRoute from './Components/PrivateRoute/PrivateRoute';

function App(props) {
    
    return ( 
        <Router>
        <AuthProvider>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path = "/signup" component = {SignUp} />
                <Route exact path = "/signin" component = {SignIn} />
                {/* <PrivateRoute path =  "/cart" component = {Cart}  /> */} // Cart component renders but I want to use this in homepage component
                <PrivateRoute exact  path = "/" component = {Homepage}  />
                
            </Switch>
        </AuthProvider>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

This is the HomePage component :

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';

import {Button,Card,Row,Col} from  'react-bootstrap';

import {useAuth} from '../../contexts/AuthContext';

import styles from './HomePage.module.css';

import {firestore} from '../../firebase';

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';



import {Navbar,Cart} from '../'


function HomePage(props) {
   
    const {currentUser} = useAuth();
    const [products,setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [itemsInCart,setItemsInCart]  = useState(0);


    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar items = {itemsInCart} /> 
            <Route path = "/cart" componenet = {Cart}></Route>  // this is not rendering Cartcomponent
            <div className = {styles.container}>
              {products.map((product,index)=> 
                <Card style={{ width: '18rem',border:'none' }} key = {index}>     
                 <Card.Img  variant="top" src={product.data.img} />
                    <Card.Body>
                      <Card.Title>{product.data.title}</Card.Title>
                        <Row>
                          <Col><Card.Title>Rs:{product.data.price}</Card.Title></Col> 
                           <Col><Button variant="warning" onClick = {() => handleAddToCard(product)}>Add to Cart</Button></Col> 
                        </Row>
                   </Card.Body>
                </Card> 
             )} 
        </div>
        </div>

    );
}

export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **BrowserRouter** should be top level tag.

like this app.js

```
 <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
      <Route exact path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
      {/* <PrivateRoute path =  "/cart" component = {Cart}  /> */} // Cart
      component renders but I want to use this in homepage component
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>;
```

I don't need to use anything related to the homepage component route.
Just specify it as route component